# Boost asio: `co_spawn` and `spawn` as async initiating functions cause segfault

Tags: c++, c++20, boost-asio, c++-coroutine, boost-coroutine

I was using both stackful coroutines (as depicted here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/composition/spawn.html) and C++20 coroutines (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/composition/cpp20_coroutines.html) in my project. Here is an example:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/awaitable.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::asio;

io_context ioctx;
void stackful_coroutine(yield_context yield);

awaitable<void> cxx_coroutine() {
  std::cout << "In cxx_coroutine" << std::endl;
  co_await spawn(ioctx, stackful_coroutine, use_awaitable);
  co_return;
}

void stackful_coroutine(yield_context yield) {
  std::cout << "In stackful_coroutine" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  co_spawn(ioctx, cxx_coroutine(), detached);
  ioctx.run();
}
```

This works with no errors and spawn is used as just another asynchronous operation.

However, when I switch the order:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/awaitable.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::asio;

io_context ioctx;
void stackful_coroutine(yield_context yield);

awaitable<void> cxx_coroutine() {
  std::cout << "In cxx_coroutine" << std::endl;
  co_return;
}

void stackful_coroutine(yield_context yield) {
  std::cout << "In stackful_coroutine" << std::endl;
  co_spawn(ioctx, cxx_coroutine(), yield);
}

int main() {
  spawn(ioctx, stackful_coroutine, detached);
  ioctx.run();
}
```

**I get a segmentation fault!**

Moreover, I also get a segmentation fault even when I only use stackful coroutines as follows:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/awaitable.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::asio;

io_context ioctx;

void stackful_coroutine(yield_context yield) {
  std::cout << "In stackful_coroutine" << std::endl;
  spawn(
      ioctx, [](auto yc) { std::cout << "Spawn inside spawn" << std::endl; },
      yield);
}

int main() {
  spawn(ioctx.get_executor(), stackful_coroutine, detached);
  ioctx.run();
}
```

I am not sure if this is a bug, or whether I am missing something...
I am using `gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0` with Boost 1.83.0.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on to a bug, introduced in Asio 1.24/Boost 1.80.0.

I've noticed a behaviorial change with commit [5bbdc9b Added new spawn() overloads that conform to the requirements for asynchronous operations](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/commit/5bbdc9b7093b7c862a3a94e40b3f4e379f8ca1e8) before¹ and checked before and after.

I can't give a satisfactory suggestion. I **can** show you what I've tried (based on your last, simplest, example).

None of the alternatives (e.g. inheriting the `yield` context for the inner coro, which is deprecated but still exists) work. Note also, the old style doesn't actually achieve the same result anyways, because the inner `spawn` is not "awaited", regardless of whether the `yield` context is inherited. ¯\*(ツ)*/¯ I guess this makes it "not a breaking change" because the functionality didn't exist before Asio 1.24.

Note I also experimented with adding work-guards to the inner handlers but it made no difference.

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59a3415b40c43eea)**

```
#define BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANLDER_TRACKING 1
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#if BOOST_ASIO_VERSION >=                                                                                    \
    10'24'00 // Asio 1.24.0,  Boost 1.80.0
             // https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_asio/history.html#boost_asio.history.asio_1_24_0___boost_1_80
    #define NEWSTYLE 1
#else
    #define NEWSTYLE 0
#endif

namespace asio = boost::asio;
asio::io_context ioctx;

void coro(asio::yield_context yield) try {
    std::cout << "Start coro" << std::endl;

#if NEWSTYLE
    auto ex = yield.get_executor();
#else
    auto ex = asio::get_associated_executor(yield);
#endif

    asio::spawn(
#if NEWSTYLE
        ioctx, // or: yield, // or: ex
#else
        yield,
#endif
        [](asio::yield_context yc) {
            std::cout << "Spawn inside spawn" << std::endl;
            post(yc); // just a suspend so we can observe scheduling orders
            std::cout << "End inside spawn" << std::endl;
        }
#if NEWSTYLE
        , yield
#endif
    );
    std::cout << "End coro" << std::endl;
} catch(...) {
    std::cout << "Here be dragons" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Boost:" << BOOST_VERSION << " Asio:" << BOOST_ASIO_VERSION << std::endl;
    asio::spawn(ioctx.get_executor(), coro
#if NEWSTYLE
        , [](std::exception_ptr) { std::cout << "Exceptional" << std::endl; }
#endif
    );
    ioctx.run();
}
```

Printing e.g.

```
Boost:107900 Asio:102202
Start coro
Spawn inside spawn
End coro
End inside spawn
```

Vs.

```
Boost:108300 Asio:102802
Start coro
Spawn inside spawn
End inside spawn
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Lastly I made sure to isolate it to Asio-only changes by switching just the ASIO version, instead of all of boost:

[image]

I would suggest raising this question at https://github.com/boostorg/asio/issues or (possibly better?) https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/issues

Comment: Issue raised! Thanks for your input :)